# Python - Plots based on text in other column

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have data like below in a DataFrame df1

```
time       duration status
10:45:00   12       Ok
11:45:00   22       Ok
12:45:00   10       Failed
13:45:00   42       Ok
14:45:00   32       Failed
```

With Matplotlib, I could plot a graph for first two columns using

```
df1.plot(y='duration',figsize=(20,10))
plt.show()
```

Now, I want to show the point in red cross (X) when the status is 'Failed' and nothing when it is 'Ok'

Can this be achieved using matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.plot(y='duration',figsize=(8,5), ax=ax)
df1[df1["status"]=="Failed"].plot(marker='x', linestyle='None', color='r', legend=False, markersize=20, ax=ax)
```

This is another way of doing it

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df1.plot(y='duration',figsize=(8,5), ax=ax)
xvals = np.where(df1["status"]=="Failed")[0] 

ax.scatter(xvals, df1[df1["status"]=="Failed"]["duration"].values, marker='x', s=100, c='r') 
plt.show()
```

[image]